# Migrate database from hybris version to another hybris updated version

Tags: database, spring-boot, updates, sap-commerce-cloud

i've just finished upgrade in my local env (hybris 1811 to 2105). After compiling and deploy the new version in qas, we've noticed that some things don't work as they should. When i deploy in the portal i selected the option 'no migrate data'. I don't know if it could be because of that. Another thing to keep in mind, the update in the hac is frozen.

Answer (score 0):

When doing an upgrade, you **always** need to perform it with data migration

Data migration does all required database changes, **new types, new properties,...** Definitely with an upgrade like that, a lot of new types and properties are added. Not running that will cause a lot of errors in your logs.

To fix this, you can deploy the same build, but with data migration enabled this time (update system)